# correct ES6 import for adding moment precise range plugin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I'm using typescript within an angular 4 project and want to use moment-precise-range-plugin.

I've installed `moment` following https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/ but i want to add the preciserange plugin http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/preciserange/.

Install for Node.js for the preciserange plugin is at https://codebox.org.uk/pages/moment-date-range-plugin and specifies `require('moment-precise-range-plugin');` but there is no Typescript install.

I've tried `import { Moment } from 'moment-precise-range-plugin';` but get the following typescript error

`Could not find a declaration file for module 'moment-precise-range-plugin'. 'c:/Users/[UserName]/app/node_modules/moment-precise-range-plugin/moment-precise-range.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm install @types/moment-precise-range-plugin if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'moment-precise-range-plugin';'`

Any ideas very much welcome!

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the moment-precise-range-plugin in an Angular 4 project and was able to import it with:

```
import 'moment-precise-range-plugin';
```

I imported it after importing moment: `import * as moment from 'moment';`

One thing to note: my TS linter still warns me that `preciseDiff()` will cause problems, but it all runs just fine. Try that out and see if it works.

Comment: for angular 7, add `@types/moment-precise-range-plugin` to your project to keep things compiling.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: I'm using Angular 10.

It works with me when import it as -> `import 'moment-precise-range-plugin';`

and add these 3 lines:

```
declare module 'moment' {
  function preciseDiff(start: string | Date | moment.Moment, end: string | Date | moment.Moment, convertToObject?: boolean): any;
}
```

Comment: Works for react too.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a definition file in src/typings.d.ts

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export = moment;

declare module 'moment' {
  interface Moment {
    preciseDiff(start: string | Date | moment.Moment): string;
  }
}
```