# Angular 12 (typescript) and moment-precise-range plugin

Tags: angular, webpack, momentjs

I'm trying to add and use [Moment Precise Range plugin](https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range) to use its main function `preciseDiff`.

I have Angular 12 project.

In my package.json I have:

```
"moment": "2.29.4",
"moment-precise-range": "0.2.0",
```

Inside component that uses that plugin I have:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-precise-range';

declare module 'moment' {
  function preciseDiff(start: string | Date | moment.Moment, end: string | Date | 
    moment.Moment, convertToObject?: boolean): any;
}
```

Then I call `preciseDiff` function:

```
moment.preciseDiff(endDate, now, true)
```

The code compiles, but I have this error:

> ERROR TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.preciseDiff is
> not a function

I tried solutions from this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379359/correct-es6-import-for-adding-moment-precise-range-plugin/50165432#50165432), but with no luck.
When I replaced

```
import 'moment-precise-range';
```

with

```
import 'moment-precise-range-plugin';
```

As suggested there, my code even won't compile.

> Error: Can't resolve 'moment-precise-range-plugin'

Comment: The problem lies in webpack; it rewrites the name of the object (as seen in the error message), but the plugin adds the `preciseDiff` function to the global `moment` object. The makers of the plugin need to make their package more module aware.

Comment: Moment is legacy and no longer supported.

Comment: @MikeOne, what is better alternative to momentJs?

Comment: I sometimes use date-fns, nice lib.

Comment: @MikeOne thanks, I tried that one, and looks great. I think I will use it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed actual plugin (in package.json)
from:

```
"moment-precise-range": "0.2.0",
```

to:

```
"moment-precise-range-plugin": "1.3.0",
```

I got it working, but then, based on [@MikeOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2295103/mikeone) comment, I tried `date-fns` plugin and this one works well, without need for any hacks. So I'm going to switch from moment-js to that one.